# How to get file path of an imported image in html5

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the file path of an imported image in html5.
My current HTML code is as followed:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>example.com</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Example.com</h1>
        <p>Import image: <input type="file" accept="image/x-png" onclick="importImage()" id="importImg"></p>
        <script src="JS.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I dont have any JS code yet as i have literraly no idea how to do it
Also no css as i just started this project, but i dont think thats essentiall

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Read documentation how forms works in HTML https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: use `change` function for your file input and then get file path like `console.log(this.files[0].mozFullPath);`

Comment: Please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

Comment: You can not get the full file path in a browser. But, why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question exactly. but i thing you want system path of input type file

Get full path of file from your system.

```
$('input[type=file]').change( function(event) {
    var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
   console.log(tmppath)
});
```